# comparison between arraylist elements

Tags: jsp, arraylist

I have an sorted arraylist having values as `30,35,35,40,50.

Here I want to find `min` and `max value` for each `array list` element.

For example ,`for first element which is 30, min value=30 and max=35. For second element i.e. 35, min val=30 and max=40` . 3rd value is 35 min val=30 and max val=35 and so on . can anyone suggest me the logic for this? I don't want to eliminate duplicate values.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and give better examples? I think nobody understands what you want.

Comment: I edited the question....now is it easy to understand ?

Comment: `For second element i.e.35, min val=30 and max=40` Why? Where is the algorithmus? How can each arraylist element have its own min and max value? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Ashwiniwaghamare I still don't understand what is min (max) of an array element? What do you mean by it?

Comment: Can anyone tell me where I can post my entire code ? So that you will get what I exactly want to do